# Get First Column Values of Selected Rows of DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using following code to Get ID(First) Column of the Selected Data Grid View Result with Button Click

```
`DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection DGV = this.dgvSearch.SelectedCells;
for (int i = 0; i <= DGV.Count - 1; i++)
{
string ID = Convert.ToString(dgvSearch.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
MessageBox.Show(ID); 
}`
```

I am getting ID in message box but for as same as the Column number of times, I just want it for once for each select row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection` instead of `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` and loop through the no of rows selected. inside the loop just give the same what u have given. replace `this.dgvSearch.SelectedCells` with `this.dgvSearch.SelectedRows`..

**update:**

```
 DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection DGV =this.dgvSearch.SelectedRows;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV)
  {
 DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
  string ID = Convert.ToString(myRow.Cells[0].Value);
  MessageBox.Show(ID); 

   }
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply
Result Count is ok But If I have selected four Rows it gives same ID four Times